# Hair emitter Object wrong orientation; Blender 3.0

Tags: particles, hair

thx in advance
I have two planes, one with a vertical tree image texture and one that is flat 'ground'.  I want to use a particle system to place the trees on the ground.  However the hair emitter has the tree the wrong way on the ground.  I do not see any particle system ways to properly orient the tree on the ground.  Before I changed the Render from Path to Object the 'hairs' had the right orientation.[image]
Surely I'm missing some basic thing.  It appears that older versions of blender had rotation controls for the hair that I cannot find in 3.0.  Also all of my objects have all transformations applied and neither object is being effected by any modifiers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Particle systems use different orientation than Viewport <sup>(because reasons)</sup>

Simply rotate the origin point of your object by 90 degrees so they match

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]Apply all transformations could be also solution.